# Docker - Securely set MySQL/MariaDB root password at build stage

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb

I'm trying to create a docker build/compose where I can securely set the root password for my MariaDB server at build/runtime rather than having to do it manually in the shell through `docker exec`. I want to be a completely hands-off build.

I have tried multiple ways of getting this to work, including BuildKit secrets, but am trying to avoid using Swarm if possible. I read that it was possible to do it using `docker compose` so I have written a YAML for it, however it does not seem to be working.

The compose seems to work fine, however when I try to update my database from a dump (this exec is just for testing so fine that it isn't hands-off) using this command:

`docker exec -i my_db_containter mysql -uroot -pmypassword < dbserver/sqlconfig/db_dump.sql`

I get this error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong here, is able to perhaps suggest an alternative solution to setting the server root password in this manner?

--

**EDIT:** After doing some more reading, it seems like even this method isn't that secure as it just seems to mount a read-only file in the container? Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can automatically and securely set the MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, ideally without swarm? If swarm really is the only option then I guess I can look into it.

--

Here is what I have so far:

docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    build:
      context: "./dbserver"
    container_name: 'my_db_container'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my_db'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/dbrootpass
    networks:
      my_net:
        ipv4_address: 203.0.113.88
    secrets:
      - dbrootpass

networks:
  my_net:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: "203.0.113.0/24"

secrets:
  dbrootpass:
    file: ./rootpass
```

rootpass:

```
mypassword
```

Comment: There is `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE` = `/rootpass` as an option. However I'm trying to understand the "Securely set" aspect of your question. What are you trying to protect the password from? a) people that can `docker exec`? b)  other on the subnet? c) `docker logs`, something else? Do you even need a *root* password in that `MYSQL_USER` / `MYSQL_PASSWORD ` if set will have full grants on the `MYSQL_DATABASE` in the container.

Comment: @danblack I'm trying to prevent the password from appearing in plain text anywhere at all. I'm not realising that whilst setting the password in an environment variable works the easiest, it can also be easily found by using something like `printenv` inside the container. Do you have any suggestions as to how I may be able to set the root/a user password without using this? I tried using `mysqladmin` but it kept giving me the same `access denied` errors, even though I hadn't set any passwords

Answer (score 1):

Create secrets:

```
$ read -p "Enter variable for MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD : " token && echo -n "$token" | podman secret create "MARIADB_PASSWORD" -
Enter variable for MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD : whynot
7f3b681f9a05729ad5b6af9d5

$  podman run --secret=MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD,type=env   --secret=MARIADB_PASSWORD,type=env  --env MARIADB_USER=bob  mariadb:10.5
```

Inside container:

```
$ podman exec -ti funny_cohen  bash
root@2583f8620571:/# ps -ef
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
mysql          1       0  0 03:31 ?        00:00:00 mysqld
root         143       0  0 03:32 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root         146     143  0 03:32 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
root@2583f8620571:/# printenv
GPG_KEYS=177F4010FE56CA3336300305F1656F24C74CD1D8
PWD=/
MARIADB_USER=bob
container=podman
HOME=/root
MARIADB_VERSION=1:10.5.10+maria~focal
GOSU_VERSION=1.12
TERM=xterm
MARIADB_MAJOR=10.5
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

It does show up in `podman inspect funny_cohen` however.